# Why isn't my Django REST Framework viewset URL resolving?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I am building an API with Django REST Framework, using:

- `Viewset`s
- Non-standard namespacing
- `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`
- `URLPathVersioning`

I am trying to cut out a lot of what I perceive to be irrelevant aspects of my application as it is large, established, and closed-source. However, if you can think of anything I have missed I will provide additional information.

I have configured my `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` to support my custom-namespaced Viewset.

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ["id", "url", "description", "source_id", "location", "test"]
        model = models.Item
        extra_kwargs = {
            "url": {
                "view_name": "api:v1:questions:item-detail",
                "lookup_field": "pk",
            }
        }
```

My `Viewset`:

```
class ItemViewSet(APIMixin, viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ItemSerializer

# This is largely inconsequential, except for maybe the versioning class.
class APIMixin(SerializerExtensionsAPIViewMixin):

    authentication_classes = [authentication.SessionAuthentication]

    filter_backends = [
        django_filters.DjangoFilterBackend,
        filters.OrderingFilter,
    ]

    ordering_fields = []

    pagination_class = pagination.DefaultPageNumberPagination

    parser_classes = [
        parsers.JSONParser,
        parsers.FormParser,
        parsers.MultiPartParser,
    ]

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
        permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions,
    ]

    versioning_class = versioning.URLPathVersioning
```

`urls.py` file:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import viewsets


router = DefaultRouter()

router.register(r"^test", viewsets.TestViewSet)

urlpatterns = [url(r"^", include(router.urls, namespace="questions"))]
```

Which is included by a series of minimal other `urls.py` files in the project which are just applying the namespacing. Not included as this does not seem to be the issue as I can prove below that namespacing is working as expected.

Loading a view from the viewset (list or detail) throws the following:

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/reverse.py" in reverse
  41.             url = scheme.reverse(viewname, args, kwargs, request, format, **extra)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/versioning.py" in reverse
  88.             viewname, args, kwargs, request, format, **extra

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/versioning.py" in reverse
  25.         return _reverse(viewname, args, kwargs, request, format, **extra)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/reverse.py" in _reverse
  60.     url = django_reverse(viewname, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, **extra)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  497.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

During handling of the above exception (Reverse for 'item-detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': UUID('380fda25-196d-41ef-93c6-5216d54561a2'), 'version': 'v1'}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['api/(?P<version>v1)/questions/^item/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'api/(?P<version>v1)/questions/^item/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$']), another exception occurred:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py" in to_representation
  393.             url = self.get_url(value, self.view_name, request, format)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py" in get_url
  331.         return self.reverse(view_name, kwargs=kwargs, request=request, format=format)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/reverse.py" in reverse
  45.             url = _reverse(viewname, args, kwargs, request, format, **extra)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/reverse.py" in _reverse
  60.     url = django_reverse(viewname, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, **extra)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  497.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

During handling of the above exception (Reverse for 'item-detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': UUID('380fda25-196d-41ef-93c6-5216d54561a2'), 'version': 'v1'}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['api/(?P<version>v1)/questions/^item/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'api/(?P<version>v1)/questions/^item/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$']), another exception occurred:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  114.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/opt/project/project/api/v1/views.py" in dispatch
  57.         return super(APIMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  505.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  465.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in raise_uncaught_exception
  476.         raise exc

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  502.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
  43.             return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  757.         ret = super().data

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  261.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  675.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in <listcomp>
  675.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  526.                 ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py" in to_representation
  408.             raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg % self.view_name)

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /api/v1/questions/item/
Exception Value: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "api:v1:questions:item-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

Whilst this is how the problem is presenting itself, during troubleshooting I've tried to remove all intermediaries and distil the problem down to its most pure form.

In the Django shell, giving (made-up) URL to the resolver succeeds. I can (importantly) see:

- The `url_name`
- The `namespaces`
- The `kwargs`

```
In [26]: resolve('/api/v1/questions/item/25/')
Out[26]: ResolverMatch(func=project.questions.api.v1.viewsets.ItemViewSet, args=(), kwargs={'version': 'v1', 'pk': '25'}, url_name=item-detail, app_names=[], namespaces=['api', 'v1', 'questions'])
```

Now, if I use the info I have gleaned from this to reverse the given URL name:

```
In [24]: reverse('api:v1:questions:item-detail', kwargs={'version': 'v1', 'pk': '25'})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoReverseMatch                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-922da70ed04c> in <module>()
----> 1 reverse('api:v1:questions:item-detail', kwargs={'version': 'v1', 'pk': '25'})

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/base.py in reverse(viewname, urlconf, args, kwargs, current_app)
     89             resolver = get_ns_resolver(ns_pattern, resolver)
     90 
---> 91     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
     92 
     93 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix(self, lookup_view, _prefix, *args, **kwargs)
    495                 "a valid view function or pattern name." % {'view': lookup_view_s}
    496             )
--> 497         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
    498 
    499 

NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'item-detail' with keyword arguments '{'version': 'v1', 'pk': '25'}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['api/(?P<version>v1)/questions/^item/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'api/(?P<version>v1)/questions/^item/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$']
```

(I am using Django's standard `reverse`, not DRF's `reverse`, so there are no versioning-related things getting in the way).

My understanding is that this exception text indicates that the URL name has matched successfully (hence the shown attempted matches), but the kwargs are not matching. However as far as I can tell I am providing the kwargs exactly as Django expects them, as per the `resolve()`ing above.

Comment: What is the path of the **urls.py**?

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The `viewname` parameter passed to [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) can contain [URL namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces), not path components.

Since the filepath is (presumably) **api/questions/urls.py**, then the `"view_name"` should be:

```py
"view_name": "api:questions:item-detail",
```